# Why is my Spring Batch Task launching with the same JOB_INSTANCE_ID for multiple job executions?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-batch, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a Spring Batch Task running on our cloud platform that will launch with the provided command line parameters, and then skip over the execution of the first Step with the following error:

```
[OUT] The job execution id 992 was run within the task execution 1325
[OUT] Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute: 
StepExecution: id=1071, version=3, name=OFileStep, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, 
writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
```

I have investigated the metadata tables in the MySQL instance that Spring Batch uses to find that the JOB_INSTANCE_ID is the same between multiple executions, when it should increment by 1 each time.

[image]

The @Bean that I have defined for the Job Configuration is:

```
@Bean
public Job job() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get(OTaskConstants.JOB_NAME)
            .listener(listener())
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(dataTransferTaskStep())
            .next(controlMTaskStep())
            .build();
}
```

Is anyone aware of what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: It is possible to have multiple job executions for the same job instance, for example when the first execution fails and you try to re-run the job again. If you launch the job with the same identifying parameters, you will attempt to (re)run the same job instance: if the last job execution failed, you will have a new job execution, otherwise Spring Batch will tell you the job instance is complete and cannot be run again (`JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException`). But in your case, you are setting a `RunIdIncrementer` so you should get a new job instance each time. How do you launch your jobs?

Answer (score 1):

Remove @Bean annotation on Job.

It causes the Job to be launched with no parameters every time you launch/start application as spring tries to load the bean and which in-turn launches the batch job.

Remove the annotation and use spring scheduler to schedule the jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Below line clearly says it all.

```
Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute:
```

Meaning the step/job already complete and can not be restarted. This is the behavior of Spring Batch. In order to by pass this we need to pass an unique argument.

In your case i see you already have RunIdIncrementer. Now question is why it is not working.

Can you see BATCH_JOB_PARMS table to see what arguments are getting passed to the job? May be you are missing something.

You can also use SimpleIncrementor. See below code for explanation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html#JobParametersIncrementer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Below code helped me resolve it. By adding params in job launcher a new **job_instance_id** is created for every run.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    Job job;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job, params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution*

Refer error message above “If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.” The formula is JobInstance = JobParameters + Job. If you do not have any parameters for JobParameters, just pass a current time as parameter to create a new JobInstance. For example,

```
    CustomJobLauncher.java

//...

@Component
public class CustomJobLauncher {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    Job job;

    public void run() {

      try {
        JobParameters jobParameters = 
          new JobParametersBuilder()
          .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
            
        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
            
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }

}
```

Source : https://mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-a-job-instance-already-exists-and-is-complete-for-parameters/